# Return and Render JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function which adds JSX to the variable `markup`. But, when the function is called, the markup is rendered as plain text rather than JSX. How do I get the string to render as JSX instead of plain text?

**Function Call**:

```
<FormGroup controlId="items">
    {this.renderItems()}
</FormGroup>
```

**`renderItems()`**:

```
renderItems() {
    let content = this.state.content;
    console.log(content);
    let markup = "<ul>";
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(content)) {
        if (value) {
            markup += "<li><Checkbox checked>" + key + "</Checkbox></li>"
        }
        else {
            markup += "<li><Checkbox>" + key + "</Checkbox></li>"
        }
    }
    markup += "</ul>";

    return (markup);
}
```

Comment: Instead of strings, you can map to an array of React elements (or at least push to an array of them)

Comment: Why not have `renderItems` returning returning JSX rather than strings?

Comment: let markup=[]; markup.push(yourJSX)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're not creating JSX elements. You're just creating strings. One way of accomplishing this would be

```
renderItems() {
  let content = this.state.content;
  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.entries(content).map(([key, value]) => (
        <li>
          <Checkbox checked={!!value}>{key}</Checkbox>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Here, we use [JSX Expressions](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx) to add dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

your markup is string not JSX

Try this

```
 renderItems() {
    let content = this.state.content;
    let markup=[]
    console.log(content);
    markup.push(<ul>);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(content)) {
        if (value) {
            markup.push(<li><Checkbox checked={true}>{ key }</Checkbox></li>)
        }
        else {
            markup.push(<li><Checkbox checked={false}>{key}</Checkbox></li>)
        }
    }
    markup.push(</ul>);

    return (markup);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The issue is you are appending ul and li as a strings so they will be treated as string but not jsx.

Since content is array of objects you can utilise.map for iteration and you will get new array of li elements. return the array by enclosing ul element.

Also you should never forget to add a key when returning jsx elements in loop. The key should be unique, the recommended way is to add a key from data if you have otherwise use index as key

```
 renderItems() {
     const { content } = this.state;
    const items = content.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index}><Checkbox checked={item.value ? true : false }>{item.value}</Checkbox></li>
     )
    return <ul>{items}</ul>
 }
```

Comment: In the question it is `<Checkbox checked>{ key }</Checkbox>`, but you used `<Checkbox checked>{item}</Checkbox>` Is it ture ?