# How to re-render a returned string as JSX, inside JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have built a form app using React. I'm using useState and useEffect which I think is pretty awesome. For brevity I include this toned down example below of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
   import DATA from './data.json'

   const [language, setLanguage] = useState('english');
   const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('Bob');

   function App() {

       const getTranslation = (reference) => {
           let dictionary = DATA[language]
           return dictionary[reference]
       }

       return (
           <React.Fragment>
               <h1>{getTranslation('HowCanWeHelp')}</h1>
           </React.Fragment>
       );

   }
```

I am attempting to build my own simple language translation mechanism that pulls the strings from a JSON file.

The data returned from
    DATA['english'][HowCanWeHelp]
is `{firstName}, How can we help you?`.

**What is returned**

`{firstName}, How can we help you?`

**What is expected**

`Bob, How can we help you?`

I'm not certain if this is even possible, but can I re-render JSX inside JSX? I've tried wrapping with `React.Fragment` tags, using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and trying my luck with `React.createElement`. A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I have read the following stackoverflow questions but the answers make little sense to me.

[Return and Render JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52809323/return-and-render-jsx)
[How to render (print) JSX as String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416939/how-to-render-print-jsx-as-string)
[Render string as JSX in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54550419/render-string-as-jsx-in-react-js)

Comment: Thank you so much @Agney for fixing the code formatting. I was struggling to get it to accept what I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the internationalisation libraries come with this feature by default. For eg. a popular internationalisation library for React, [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) can implement it with:

```
i18next.t('HowCanWeHelp', { firstName: "name" });
```

[Docs on i18next interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation)

If you don't want a complete internationlisation solution and prefer your own dictionary solution, you can go with a microtemplating library like [pupa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pupa)

```
import pupa from "pupa";

return (
  <React.Fragment>
     <h1>{
       pupa(getTranslation('HowCanWeHelp'), {
         firstName: "name"
       })
     }</h1>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string's `replace` method:

```
const getTranslation = (reference) => {
  let dictionary = DATA[language]
  return dictionary[reference].replace('{firstName}', firstName);
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-replace-message-with-state-value?file=Hello.js) for your ref.